# Submenú mal desplegado en Mozilla

Tags: html5, css3, google-chrome, firefox

Buenas a todos y todas.

Hace poco hice una pregunta para hacer un menú responsive con una anchura del 100% de la web 
[en este enlace (gracias por las respuestas)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20672/men%C3%BA-de-navegaci%C3%B3n-con-100-de-ancho/20687#20687.)

Tras realizar los cambios y ver que en **Chrome funciona a las mil maravillas**, una vez entro a testear con Mozilla, **el submenú no se despliega correctamente**.

[image: Imagen en Chrome]

**Google Chrome**

[image: Mozilla]
**Mozilla Firefox**

Dejo el código a continuación para ver si tenéis alguna solución.
PD: Mi versión de Mozilla es la 48 y estoy en Ubuntu 16.04.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div.w3-content { 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index: 0;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #2f3036;
}
/*Hacer que la imagen no se mueva */

#img-nav { padding-top: 0px !important; height: 100px; }
/*Create a horizontal list*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/

li:hover a {
  background: #19c589;
  height: 100px;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.submenu-li{
    min-height:30px !important;
}
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
  display:block;
  top: 100px;
  min-width:200px;
  width: calc(100%/6);
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/

ul {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
}

ul li {
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
}

ul li a {
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
    background: #f3f3f3;
  }
  ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover { display:inline; width:100%; }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #img-nav {
    display: none;
  }
    /* quitamos el line height */
    li a {
        line-height: 0px;
    }
    /*ocultamos el slider */
    div.w3-content { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="img-nav"><img src="images/nav/logo3.png" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Aula Virtual</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li class="submenu-li"><a href="#">Test Online</a></li>
    <li class="submenu-li"><a href="#">Test DGT</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Resultado Teórico</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nuestros Vehículos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Permisos</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/imagenes slider/slider.png" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
  <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottomleft" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="w3-left w3-padding-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-padding-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PD: Gracias a todos/as por la paciencia y las futuras respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probando en tu mismo ambiente, (sin probar en otros navegadores) agregando `position: relative` al contenedor de los elementos del menú y usando posicionamiento absoluto a la izquierda para el submenú, parece solucionarse:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div.w3-content { 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index: 0;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #2f3036;
}
/*Hacer que la imagen no se mueva */

#img-nav { padding-top: 0px !important; height: 100px; }
/*Create a horizontal list*/

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
/*Style for menu links*/

li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/

li:hover a {
  background: #19c589;
  height: 100px;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

li:hover ul a:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/

li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
.submenu-li{
    min-height:30px !important;
}
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
  display:block;
  top: 100px;
  min-width:200px;
  width: calc(100%/6);
  left: 0;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
  display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/

ul {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
}

ul li {
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    position: relative;
}

ul li a {
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  ul {
    position: static;
    display: none;
    background: #f3f3f3;
  }
  ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover { display:inline; width:100%; }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  ul li,
  li a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #img-nav {
    display: none;
  }
    /* quitamos el line height */
    li a {
        line-height: 0px;
    }
    /*ocultamos el slider */
    div.w3-content { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>CSS Only Navigation Menu</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="img-nav"><img src="images/nav/logo3.png" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Aula Virtual</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li class="submenu-li"><a href="#">Test Online</a></li>
    <li class="submenu-li"><a href="#">Test DGT</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Resultado Teórico</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nuestros Vehículos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Permisos</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:100%;">
  <img class="mySlides" src="images/imagenes slider/slider.png" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
  <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottomleft" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="w3-left w3-padding-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-padding-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
    <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfecto. Funciona. Gracias